# Home hosting using no-ip

Tags: dns, dynamic-dns

I have a dynamic host from no-ip witch gets updated with my ip address,the webserver works ok.

I also have a domain name registered, and I want to resolve to this dynamic host.

If I run a DNS server that my registered domain will point to, can the DNS server redirect me to the dynamic DNS?

What I am tring to do is something like this :

REQUEST ( www.mydomain.com ) - > DNS ( my dns server ) - > DNS (no-ip dynamic host) -> My IP

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a CNAME record on your DNS server for www.mydomain.com which points to your no-ip hostname

eg at your dns admin panel

- if there is already a record for www, then remove it Note down what
  it is set to so that your can re-instate it if ever you want to.
- add new record of type CNAME WWW which points to yourname.noip.org
- Note, your virtual host at home would need to be set up for
  yourname.noip.org

Answer (score 1):

You also have to make sure that your home ISP doesn't block inbound port 80 traffic, many of them do.  If they do, then you will need to use an alternate port and configure your router and/or server to use that port.